# Why does the SAGA raster calculator fail when used in a Processing model?

Tags: qgis, raster-calculator, qgis-processing

I have a problem with the modeler and the saga raster calculator. When I'm using the raster caculator without the modeler it works fine. When I'm using the saga raster calculator in my model I always get the messege: "Oooops! The following output layers could not be open test: C:\Users\miller\AppData\Local\Temp\processing\4a78580e485a40d199a2fa138960042c\R‌​ESULTALG2.tif" –

Is this a known problem? Some weeks ago everything worked fine.

Comment: This issue suggests that a similar issue was recently fixed: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/8877. Did you try to update your processing plugin?

Comment: I have the newest plugin version (2.0-20131120). It worked some update before. But now its still not working.

Comment: I guess it's not the same issue that you mentioned.

Comment: I would suggest to open a [bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports).